# Google Sheets Importing Citi Savings APY

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to import the current APY data (by scraping the numerical value from the string on the page) for several different banks into a single Google Sheet. I have been successful with many, by using `IMPORTXML`, but with Citi, I received an "Imported content is empty" error.

I did some searching on SO, and I am currently under the impression that the issue is that Citi uses JavaScript and Google Sheets `IMPORTXML` doesn't. I have found a thread that suggests parsing the `JSONS`, but U haven't had luck with the couple of tutorials I've read.

I have tried getting the data (0.50% APY) from [here](https://online.citi.com/US/banking/citi.action?ID=savings-account-overview) and [here](https://online.citi.com/US/ag/banking/savings-account/).

There are many others, but most require entering a zip code or selecting an option out of a dropdown. This one has the data with no extra input required. Using `IMPORTDATA` on either URL doesn't seem to return useful information for getting the APY, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about the output values you expect. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: My goal is to get the APY (currently 0.50%). Ideally output would be numerical, but a string is just fine for now as I can convert it if necessary down the road.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I checked the value of `0.50%` from your 2 URLs. But unfortunately, it seems that the value is created by Javascript. By this, in the current stage, IMPORTXML, IMPORTHTML and Google Apps Script cannot directly retrieved the value. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: I think best to look into some other web scraping/automation software, maybe Puppeteer. Or try to use an API. Though if you are looking for software recommendations then you should head over to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or another stack site

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)'s answer:

I checked the value of 0.50% from your 2 URLs. But unfortunately, it seems that the value is created by Javascript. By this, in the current stage, `IMPORTXML`, `IMPORTHTML` and Google Apps Script cannot directly retrieved the value.

---

#### [iansedano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10445017/iansedano)'s answer:

I think best to look into some other web scraping/automation software, maybe Puppeteer. Or try to use an API. Though if you are looking for software recommendations then you should head over to [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) or another stack site.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll look into other software.

Comment: Hi - could you please mark this question as "answered", otherwise it shows up in our "unanswered" section...

Comment: It is ok to turn comments into answers, but you should make those answers community wikis as they are not really your own. It is not "fair" you will gain rep for them... I see you've done so a few times. Please see [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat)

Comment: @Tomerikoo ok, done

Comment: @Tomerikoo [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117268/1108617) it says "Steal comments that answer the question and post them as an answer".

Comment: You are free of course to do whatever you choose, just try to give proper attribution. A quote formatting shows that it is not your own content and a link to the comment itself can be helpful